# MDI Forms in .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, forms, .net-3.5, mdi

Is there any improvemens or new features in .NET 3.5 Windos Forms in creating MDI Forms as compared to .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer at MSDN:

[Additions to Windows Forms for the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762963.aspx)